# Android: What's wrong with my fragment transition animation?

Tags: android, animation, transition, android-fragments

I just need plain slide in and slide out animation for Fragment transition, below is my code:
slide_in_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="true">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="700">
</translate>
</set>
```

slide_out_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="700">
</translate>
</set>
```

the code I used:

```
SomeFragment frag = SomeFragment.newInstance(foo);
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
ft.replace(R.id.the_fragment, frag);
ft.addToBackStack(null);

ft.commit();
```

The result looks very stranges, when the transition starts, the current fragment disappears without animation, the entering fragment comes(from left) like a scrolling paper. What's wrong with my animation xml code?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it seems like ObjectAnimator is not in the Compatibility pack....

Answer (score 5):

getSupportFragmentManager() means you are using the Compatibility Package for Fragments, I guess.
I have the same problem, which is no animation happening at all.

See http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5ef5ba1be9f40c56/a846578d91a032c0?hide_quotes=yes#msg_8ca017c473818a04

Answer (score 3):

Google has updated the compatibility library and the transitions have been fixed. You guys should update your compatiblity library from the android sdk/avd manager.

Comment: i confirm, last google support lib'version does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found a cool post [here](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2012/06/fragment-transactions-reference.html) about the Fragment Compatibility library animations issue, i took second approach

> ..... Call FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(), referencing either animators or animations (depending on whether you're using the
>   compatibility library or not).  What is interesting is that
>   setCustomAnimations() affects all fragment transitions added to the
>   transaction after it is called.  So you need to call
>   setCustomAnimations() before you want it used, and you can actually
>   setup multiple different custom animations for each part of a
>   transaction (with a call to setCustomAnimations() before each
>   add()/remove()/attach()/detach()/show()/hide()/replace())......

like this

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_up_in,R.anim.push_up_out);
ft.commit();
ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_up_in,R.anim.push_up_out);
if (fragment1.isHidden()) {
ft.show(fragment1);
} else {
ft.hide(fragment1);

}
ft.commit();
```

With this i solved the problem for api level 11 hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ViewPager

```
mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(YourFragmentsSize);
```

This line solved my problem, hope works for you too. [Referanced from this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9684022/1171484)