# How to have a MapView in a fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to create an Activity to look exactly like this. Upper half of it would be the MapView and the lower half of it would be the list of surrounding places provided by google maps places API. I'm done with the both the parts but separately. Not able to integrate it in two fragments in one Activity. The obvious error is to that MapView won't work outside a MapActivity. So what is the hack around for this?

Edit: The biggest problem I am facing right now is integrating RoboGuice, ActionBarSherlock and MapActivity into one Activity that I can extend from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in GoogleCode (Add support for MapFragment), and one of the commenters posted a workaround

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15347#c29

I haven't tried it myself, but it seems to work

Check this other question, which is related to the workaround

[MapActivity in TabHost Fragment disappearing after tab switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828358/mapactivity-in-tabhost-fragment-disappearing-after-tab-switch/10387096#10387096)

Also, read the bug comments, it's always interesting

Comment: Do check the Edit. That is the biggest problem I am facing right now.

Comment: ah, sorry I can't help you there. Good luck! Would you like me to delete my answer?

Comment: No this has been bloody helpful. Let me up-vote it to help others out if they drop in here.